# RegEx - Search for Word and Output Last Decimal Number on Line

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to use RegEx to parse the Total Hours working in a pay period from a PDF timesheet.

For example:

Total Overtime Hours:
Total Hours: 2.2 1.0 1.0 3.5 5.0 12.7
Signature:

```
(?<=Total Hours:*(?:.*?( )+){6}).*
```

The Total Hours will always be the last number on the line that starts with "Total Hours:"

The above RegEx code works for most employees who work 5 days a week but breaks if they work more or less than 5 days as in the example below:

Total Overtime Hours:
Total Hours: 2.2 1.0 1.0 3.5 5.0 6.3 19.0
Signature:

[regexr.com/7hci1](https://regexr.com/7hci1)

Any thoughts on the adjustments I can make to always grab the last decimal number of the row that starts with "Total Hours:"?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `(?<=Total Hours:.*?)\d*\.?\d+$` then. See https://regexr.com/7hcid. What is the programming language?

Comment: You can use a capture group `\bTotal Hours:[\d. ]*\s(\d*\.?\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/bOx9XP/1

Comment: Thank you both, Wiktor's solution works great on regexr.com with multiline flag on but doesn't seem to work in Power Automate Desktop (Parse Text action) that I've been using for all of my other RegEx extractions as I think it's set to global by default (vs multiline) 

Bird, I see your solution works well on regex101.com but doesn't seem to work on regexr.com for some reason.

Any suggested tweaks to get to work without multi-line enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: @Koprowski You have to enable the multiline flag due to the anchor `$`, see https://regexr.com/7hcjn

Comment: It is just a matter of using it inline: `(?m)(?<=Total Hours:.*?)\d*\.?\d+$`. And another tweak that might not be necessary: ``(?m)(?<=Total Hours:.*?)\d*\.?\d+(?=\r?$)``

Comment: Thank you, the first tweak didn't work but the last one is working perfectly in Power Automate Desktop, thank you!

(?m)(?<=Total Hours:.*?)\d*\.?\d+(?=\r?$)

Answer (score 1):

The .NET compliant regex you can use is

```
(?m)(?<=Total Hours:.*?)\d*\.?\d+(?=\r?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUqrFz/1). The point is to set the multiline mode on using the inline modifier `(?m)` at the start of the pattern (it will make `$` match right before the line feed (`\n`) character or end of string). Since `$` will only match before the newline char or end of string, you will have to allow a carriage return char, `\r`, so instead of a `$` anchor, you need `(?=\r?$)` positive lookahead, that matches either before `\r\n`, or before `\n`, or end of string.

To match any text between `Total Hours:` and the last decimal/int number (with no sign), you need to use `.*?` pattern, not its greedy counterpart `.*`, since it will "eat up" any optional chars matched with the `\d*\.?` part.

*More Details*:

- `(?m)` - an inline modifier making `$` match a position right before the newline, LF, char
- `(?<=Total Hours:.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `Total Hours:` and any zero or more chars other than line feed char, as few as possible
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=\r?$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with an optional carriage return char and then a newline char or end of string.